# Iterating in a dictionary with swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type

I am learning swift and I am trying to iterate in a dictionary. Can you please tell me why the variable l is nil at the end

```
let LandsDictionary = ["DE":"Germany", "FR":"France"]

var l:String?

for land in LandsDictionary{
    l?+=land
}
print (l)
```

Comment: Are you able to get to execute this code ? Because compiler will never allow you to do this -   l?+=land  as you're trying to assign a tuple to optional string.

Comment: Also let us know which value are you trying to read to the variable l ?

Comment: I am executing it in Playground. Also this is not working   for (key,land) in LandsDictionary{
    l?+=land
}

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? "DEFR", "GermanyFrance", "DE:Germany, FR:France" or perhaps something else?

Comment: @vadian The value for a key in a dictionary can be optional. However if you set a value for key as nil, it'd be equivalent to removing that key from the dictionary.

Comment: @iamyogish, sorry I deleted my comment. When iterating (reading) a dictionary there cannot be optional keys / values.

Comment: @vadian Agreed :). However we can read the value of dictionary to an optional right?. I mean if value for a key is of type string, we can read the value to an variable of type optional string which is a valid scenario which would be helpful when you try to read value for a key which doesn't exist in dictionary.

Comment: @iamyogish The strong type system of Swift encourages the developers to use non-optionals as much as possible. This question is about iterating over a dictionary and there are no optionals.

Comment: @vadian Yeah I totally agree with what you're saying. I am sorry if I seem like I am trying to make an argument but what I want to say is, there is no harm in declaring - var l:String? and then trying to read the value of dictionary to variable l.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is example how you can get keys and values in two different ways. Try to read about collection bit more.

```
let LandsDictionary = ["DE":"Germany", "FR":"France"]

var keys :String = ""

var values :String = ""

//Iteration is going on properly and fetching key value.
for land in LandsDictionary {

    print (land) // "DE":"Germany" and "FR":"France"

    keys += land.0

    values +=  land.1
}

//All keys
print(keys)

//All values
print(values)

//If you would like to recive all values and all keys use standart method of the collection.

let allKeys = LandsDictionary.keys

let allValues = LandsDictionary.values
```

Answer (score 3):

Since all keys and values are non-optional in this dictionary, there is not need to use optional variables.

```
let landsDictionary = ["DE":"Germany", "FR":"France"]

var l = ""

// the underscore represents the unused key
for (_, land) in landsDictionary {
  l += land
}
print (l) // "GermanyFrance"
```

or without a loop

```
let v = Array(landsDictionary.values).joinWithSeparator("")
print (v) // "GermanyFrance"
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I assume you're trying to read the Country names to the variable "l".

Try with this code snippet,

```
let LandsDictionary = ["DE":"Germany", "FR":"France"]

var l:String?
//You need to assign an initial value to l before you start appending country names.
//If you don't assign an initial value, the value of variable l will be nil as it is an optional.
//If it is nil, l? += value which will be executed as optional chaining will not work because optional chaining will stop whenever nil is encountered.
l = ""

for (key, value) in LandsDictionary{
    l? += value
}
print (l)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For iterating a dictionary

```
 for (key , value) in LandsDictionary{
                print(key)
                print(value)
            }
```